# How to make stack panel in GWT that looks like Outlook

Tags: gwt

The default GWT StackPanel is not enough good, i want to have functionality similar to outlook stack panel. May be there is already something exists?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog](http://gwtfuse.blogspot.com/2008/11/how-to-make-gwt-stack-panel-outlook.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using EXT-GWT, a much prettier fully compliant GWT UI toolkit then this might be more what your looking for.

[The Example](http://extjs.com/examples/layouts/accordionlayout.html).

GXT as it is also called can do lots of good things for a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I took the TabPanel source code and modified it so it drew the tabs to look like Outlook.